# casting 2 generics types from one to the other

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have a many interfaces each with 2 implementations of it:

```
public interface Foo{/**/}

public class ModelFoo : Foo {/**/}

public class ViewModelFoo : Foo {/**/}
```

Now I have a repositoryInterface and 2 Implementations with generic functions in it:

```
    public interface Repository
    {
        ICollection<TModel> GetAll<TModel>();
    }

    public class ModelRepository : Repository
    {
        private IDictionary<Type, Type> typeMapping = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();
        private DbContext context;
        public ICollection<TModel> GetAll<TModel>()
        {
            var implType = typeMapping[typeof(TModel)];
            var ctxSet = context.Set(implType);

            return new EFWrapCollection<TModel>(Enumerable.Cast<object>(ctxSet).ToList());
        }

    }
```

The first implementation of the interface will load all Models from the database. The dictionary **typemapping** is needed for typemapping between the interface type and the concrete type. EFWrapCollection wraps the paramter to TModel type.

In the **typemapping** there are pairs as follows:

```
(typeof(Foo), typeof(ModelFoo)),
(typeof(Bar), typeof(ModelBar)),
...
```

The usage will be as follows:

```
        var rep = new ModelRepository(context);
        rep.GetAll<Foo>();
```

This will return all ModelFoo's from the database with the typeparameter **Foo**. Now I want to do the following:

```
    public class ViewModelRepository : Repository
    {
        private IDictionary<Type, Type> typeMapping = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();
        private Repository repository;
        public ICollection<TModel> GetAll<TModel>()
        {
            var result = repository.getAll<TModel>();
            //now i have the problem that i need a cast 
            //but I dont know hot to achieve it
        }
    }
```

In this repository class there is also a **typemapping**. This attribute holds all mappings between interface type and viewmodel type:

```
(typeof(Foo), typeof(ViewModelFoo)),
(typeof(Bar), typeof(ViewModelBar)),
.....
```

The cast should be a cast to the Viewmodeltype. I know how to cast 2 concrete classes, but here I have the problem, that this repository is generic and I dont know the type in the first place.

**EDIT**

Why I need the cast (or mapping):

In the database there are only Models of the type **Model** and I want to cast (or map) the type **Model** into the type **ViewModel**.

Comment: It seems like you should be doing mapping, not casting.

Comment: @juharr yes, mapping is maybe the better term here. but I do not know how to achieve the mapping here

Comment: I'm currently not sure what exactly you try to do. Your method `GetAll<TModel>()` returns `ICollection<TModel>`. Maybe you can call `.ToList()` on the returned value from `repository.getAll<TModel>()`. But I'm sure that this is not what you expect. It is also unclear how to decide between returning `ModelFoo` or `ViewModelFoo`. My guess is that the call `repository.getAll<TModel>()` is wrong and confusing me. Maybe you try to call `repository.getAll<typeMapping[TModel]>()` (not compiling :-) but you don't know how to do that. Am I right? Yes: maybe I can help you. No: Please clearify.

Comment: Could you explain why you need a cast? you seem to get a collection of TModel and want to return a collection of TModel. The need for casting is not obvious.

Comment: added the reason why I want to do that

Comment: Okay. You specify the interface and try to get the `ViewModel` whereas `Model` is stored in the database. So far so good. How do you create a `ViewModel` out of a `Model`? That is called mapping. There's no way to cast. But there are a lot of ways - automapper, copy all properties, ... What is the way you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing apples and oranges. You shouldn't be tracking types inside of the repository. The repository should be specific to the type it works with.

What you can do instead is create a generic repository and pass it the type it should work with. The context has a generic `Set<T>` method you can take advantage of:

```
public class Repository<T> 
{
    private DbContext context;
    public ICollection<T> GetAll()
    {            
        var items = context.Set<T>();
        return new EFWrapCollection<T>(items);
    }
}
```

I am not entirely sure why you are using that `EFWrapCollection` but I guess you have your reasons.

I am guessing by now you have realized it's not a very good idea to pass EF objects around, unless you manage the lifetime of the context appropriately. The type mapping can be handled in many different ways. I suggest you look at AutoMapper. You can create a class that maps objects for you and let AutoMapper do most of the work, then provide custom mappings for those not-so-straight-forward properties:

https://cpratt.co/using-automapper-getting-started/

Here is a quick excerpt from the link, to give you an idea:

```
public static class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static void RegisterMappings()
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<ModelFoo, ViewModelFoo>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Author,
                       opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Author.Name));
    }
}
```

By the way, the world will appreciate it if you follow conventions and prefix your interfaces with the letter I (e.g. `IRepository`). It really makes reading code a lot easier. Good luck!